# How to align UIBezierPath circle dashes

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I am trying to draw a compass using UIBezierPath and adding dashes to the line to mark North, South, East, West directions and points in between. The dashes seem offset (they're not aligned), particularly in the North and South directions and the way I am doing it seems to add an extra dash when the path is closing.

```
let windCircleOrigin = CGPoint(x: self.center.x * 1.3, y: self.bounds.height / 2.0 - 10)
let windCircleRadius = CGFloat(self.bounds.height * 0.3)
let windCirclePath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: windCircleOrigin, radius: windCircleRadius,startAngle: 0,  endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI) * 2.0, clockwise: true)
        windCirclePath.lineWidth = 6
let dashes: [CGFloat] = [windCirclePath.lineWidth * 0, windCirclePath.lineWidth * 3 ]
        windCirclePath.setLineDash(dashes, count: dashes.count
            , phase: 0.0)
UIColor.whiteColor().setFill()
UIColor.whiteColor().setStroke()
windCirclePath.stroke()
textView(self.windSpeedLabel! + " mph", x: windCircleOrigin.x - 20.0, y: windCircleOrigin.y - 8.0, color: UIColor.whiteColor(), width: 50.0, height: 20.0)
textView("N", x: windCircleOrigin.x - 7.0, y: windCircleOrigin.y - 70.0, color: UIColor.whiteColor(), width: 20, height: 20)
textView("S", x: windCircleOrigin.x - 7.0, y: windCircleOrigin.y + 50.0, color: UIColor.whiteColor(), width: 20, height: 20)
textView("W", x: windCircleOrigin.x - 70.0, y: windCircleOrigin.y - 8.0, color: UIColor.whiteColor(), width: 20, height: 20)
textView("E", x: windCircleOrigin.x + 60.0, y: windCircleOrigin.y - 8.0, color: UIColor.whiteColor(), width: 20, height: 20)

func textView(text: String, x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, color: UIColor, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {
    let textView = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(x, y, width, height))
    textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
    textView.textColor = color
    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    textView.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 12.0)
    textView.text = text
    self.addSubview(textView)
}
```

[image]

[image: Without Dashes]

Comment: I would recommend drawing each tick separately as a radial line, rather than trying to use one circumferential dashed line.

Comment: Can you show result of startAngle: 0,  endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI), ...?

Comment: @Shoaib you mean without the dashes?

Comment: @jtbandes Using UIBezierPaths? How would I go about doing that and maintaining the circle like appearance?

Comment: @wxcoder the half circle with endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI)

Comment: @Shoaib I edited the first post to show the circle without the dashes. CGFloat(M_PI) = 3.14159

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead, I would recommend drawing each tick individually. Then you can easily control their location.

Something like this:

```
let path = UIBezierPath()
let innerRadius: CGFloat = 50
let outerRadius: CGFloat = 60
let numTicks = 24

for i in 0..<numTicks {
    let angle = CGFloat(i) * CGFloat(2*M_PI) / CGFloat(numTicks)
    let inner = CGPoint(x: innerRadius * cos(angle), y: innerRadius * sin(angle))
    let outer = CGPoint(x: outerRadius * cos(angle), y: outerRadius * sin(angle))
    path.moveToPoint(inner)
    path.addLineToPoint(outer)
}
```

[image]

Then you can stroke this path with whatever lineWidth (and lineCapStyle) you want.

Comment: I was going to recommend the same thing (Voted).

Comment: To control the center point can you use `addArcWithCenter` ? Right now it's center on the top left corner of my view.

Comment: addArcWithCenter is for curved lines. These tick marks are straight lines. You can adjust the center by moving the `x` and `y` values.

Answer (score 1):

Using a CGPath it is pretty easy. Not sure if the same can be done using UIBezierPath.

**Swift 5.0**

```
path.copy(dashingWithPhase: 0, lengths: [(.pi * radius) / dashCount])
```